# Adding SharePoint 2007 server in Windows Azure Active Directory for SSO

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365

So I am using Windows Azure AD (WAAD) behind my O365 Apps. In SharePoint Online there are some link to documents which are pointing back to my SharePoint 2007 Library. AD behind them is same and I want that any user who is clicking the links should not get an authorization prompt (given he has the access to document) and get the document directly.

I wanted to know whether it is possible to add SharePoint 2007 server as a registered app in Windows Azure Active Directory for SSO ?